# How to assign value of a 2D array to an integer, in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to assign the greater value in this 2D array to the integer "big", but i get **"error: assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'int [2]'**. What am i doing wrong and how can this be fixed?

Thanks

```
{

int a[2][2]={1,2,3,4};
int big=0;

for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<2; i++)
    {
        if(a[j]>a[i] && a[j]>big)
        {
            big=a[j];
        }

    else {
           big=a[i];
         }
     }
   }

      cout<<big;
}
```

Comment: The error message says it.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to know what can be done to assign the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a[2][2]` is an two dimensional array.

In your code,

```
big=a[j];
```

you were trying to assign the single dimensional integer array to integer variable.

to get the individual element from the two dimensional array, use the following syntax.

```
big=a[index1][index2]
```

Explanation for error statement:

```
error: assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'int [2]'
```

you were assigning a single dimensional array `int [2]` to integer value. Both are incompatible types